# Turtlebot navigation on Hydro, OSX

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-hydro, macosx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see that there are clear instructions given to install turtlebot navigation, such as the one here http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/hydro/Installation

I would like to use my machine with OS X 10.8 and ROS Hydro(Installed already) to communicate to the turtlebot through the turtlebot navigation stack.

Can someone give instructions on how I can install the turtlebot stack on my current setup?

Right now this is the procedure I am trying to follow.

```
$ mkdir ~/turtlebot_ws
$ cd ~/turtlebot_ws
$ source /path/to/hydro/install/setup.bash
$ rosinstall_generator turtlebot_launch --deps --exclude RPP --tar > turtlebot-hydro.rosinstall
$ wstool init src -j8 openni-hydro.rosinstall
$ rosdep install --from-paths ./src --ignore-src -y --skip-keys "libopenni-dev libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev ftdi-eeprom avahi-daemon avahi-utils libftdi-dev libavahi-core-dev redis-server libusb-dev libavahi-client-dev"
```

If you see the last command, there are too many keys that need to be skipped because there occurs an error like this for each of the package specified above.

`zeroconf_avahi: No definition of [libavahi-client-dev] for OS [osx]`

after this I did

```
$ catkin_make install
```

Expectedly, I got the following errors, since I had skipped all the packages while I was installing the dependencies through rosdep.

```
Users/Siva/turtlebot_ws/src/kobuki_core/kobuki_ftdi/src/ftdi_kobuki.cpp:60:10: fatal error: 'ftdi.h' file not found
#include <ftdi.h>
         ^
In file included from /Users/Siva/turtlebot_ws/src/kobuki_core/kobuki_ftdi/src/find_devices.cpp:16:
/Users/Siva/turtlebot_ws/src/kobuki_core/kobuki_ftdi/include/kobuki_ftdi/scanner.hpp:45:10: fatal error: 'usb.h' file not found
#include <usb.h>
         ^
In file included from /Users/Siva/turtlebot_ws/src/kobuki_core/kobuki_ftdi/src/flasher.cpp:15:
/Users/Siva/turtlebot_ws/src/kobuki_core/kobuki_ftdi/src/../include/kobuki_ftdi/scanner.hpp:45:10: fatal error
```

Kindly help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158641/turtlebot-navigation-on-hydro,-osx/) by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2014-04-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-04-29**:
I don't know what software is involved to get this level of Turtlebot support working. The general process for installing any ROS package on OS X is similar to my answer to your other question: http://answers.ros.org/question/158546/openni-and-kinect-on-hydro-osx-108/?answer=158751#post-id-158751

**Comment by [anaderi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18496/anaderi/) on 2014-05-26**:
Upvote the question. I fail to build one of turtlebot_simulator dependecies: create_gazebo_plugins

**Comment by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on 2014-05-26**:
Hi, Can you post the error that you are encountering. Please add another question for that.

**Comment by [anaderi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18496/anaderi/) on 2014-05-26**:
Here it is: http://answers.ros.org/question/169971/fail-to-build-create_gazebo_plugins-package-on-mac-os-x-109/

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-05-28**:
This way you can get turtlebot_simulator compiled on 10.9: http://answers.ros.org/question/169971/fail-to-build-create_gazebo_plugins-package-on-mac-os-x-109/?answer=170726#post-id-170726

**Comment by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on 2014-05-28**:
Hi, I need the actual turtlebot packages to run my turtlebot and teleop it with my keyboard. Kindly guide me on that.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-05-28**:
Have you tried to follow the instructions that @William suggested in the comments above (replacing openni_camera with whatever packages you need)?

**Comment by [karthik_ms](https://answers.ros.org/users/10391/karthik_ms/) on 2014-05-28**:
@demmeln Edited the question with my results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Like in my answer for the other question, make sure that you call `rosdep update` regularly, in particular if you notice keys are not being resolved (OS X is far less covered than e.g. Ubuntu). If you ignore keys, you often have to still install libraries yourself. `brew search ftdi` and `brew search usb` helps. In this case you need `brew install libftdi0 libusb`.

Once you find out the correct resolution of a missing key, you can always edit this file to contribute to the rosdep rules for OS X: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml

I have recently added `libftdi` and `libusb` has been there also for some time.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0